# Как сделать программу которая выключает компютер на python?

Tags: python

Это должно бить типа когда запускаешь и через 10с комп вырубаеться

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Цель ясна, какие попытки вы сделали и какой собственно у вас вопрос?

Comment: сделать так: изучить немного питон, найти подходящие модули, написать код, который будет выполнять указанную задачу

Comment: Вы должны показать свои попытки, решения этой задачи.

Answer (score 1):

**base.py**

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class ComputerBase(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def shutdown(self):
        ...
```

**computer.py**

```
import os
from base import ComputerBase


class Computer(ComputerBase):
    """Класс управления компьютером"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def shutdown(self, delay=30):
        """Выключает компьютер через указанное время"""
        return os.system(f"shutdown /s /t {delay}")
```

**main.py**

```
from computer import Computer


def main():
    my_computer = Computer()
    my_computer.shutdown(delay=10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```